Report of DefaultApiVersionReporter lib call when the HttpContext is disposed
I have problem in my Startup.cs Configure. When the ctx.RequestServices is disposed, at the end of the app.Use, it is called automatically the Report of the DefaultApiVersionReporter that is searching for:
/// RequestServices is disposed already and I have exception
context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService
My Configuration function is:
   public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   {
       app.Use(async (context, next) =>
       {
           try
           {
               await next();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               _logger.Error(ex, "Received exception during pipeline");
               throw;
           }
       }); ///// AFTER this line the RequestServices is already disposed and after this line it  is called the Report function

       base.Configure(app);

       app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>().ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
       {
           var addreses = app.ServerFeatures?.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()?.Addresses;

           _logger.Info("Listening addressed: {@address}", addreses);
           }
       );
       app.UseBranchWithServices<PreviewStartup>("/preview", Configuration);
       app.UseBranchWithServices<QueryStartup>("/query", Configuration);

       //optional demand offer routes
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Arkive.PublicOfferDatabase")))
       {
           app.UseBranchWithServices<GMEPublicOfferStartup>("/gmepublicoffer", Configuration);
       }

       app.UseBranchWithServices<ApiStartup>("", Configuration);
   }



    public static IApplicationBuilder UseBranchWithServices<TStartup>(this IApplicationBuilder app, string url, IConfiguration configuration) where TStartup : class
    {
        var feature = app.ServerFeatures;

        var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .UseParentServiceProvider(app.ApplicationServices, configuration)
            .UseFakeServer(feature)
            .UseStartup<TStartup>()
            .Build();

        var lifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();            
        var r2 = lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => webHostBuilder.StopAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());

        async Task branchDelegate(HttpContext ctx)
        {
            var server = webHostBuilder.Services.GetRequiredService<FakeServer>();

            var nestedFactory = webHostBuilder.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

            using var nestedScope = nestedFactory.CreateScope();
            ctx.RequestServices = new BranchedServiceProvider(ctx.RequestServices, nestedScope.ServiceProvider);
            await server.Process(ctx);
        }

        webHostBuilder.Start();

        return app.Map(url, builder =>
        {
            builder.Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
            {
                var keepAlive = r2;
                await branchDelegate(context);
            });
        });
    }

I don't know if someone have an idea to avoid the disposing of the context.RequestServices after the scope. Problem started after last AspVersioning version
---> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Asp.Versioning.ISunsetPolicyManager' has been registered..
I have tried to initialize the RequestService in different point but still I have same problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
